# MongoDB query does not result

Tags: php, sql, mongodb

I wanted to make an equivalent of the following SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM pattern_object_values WHERE (pattern_object_id=1 && value>1977 && 
                                           value<1986)
                                           || (pattern_object_id=2 && value>5000 && 
                                           value<950000);
```

MongoDB query:

```
$mongoDB->find(array('$or'=>
                            array(
                                array(
                                    '$and'=>array(
                                                array('pattern_object_id'=>1),                                
                                                array('value'=>array('$gte'=>1977,'$lte'=>1986))
                                        )
                                    )
                            ),array(
                                array(
                                    '$and'=>array(
                                                array('pattern_object_id'=>2),                                
                                                array('value'=>array('$gte'=>5000,'$lte'=>95000))
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                      ));
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Post your sample documents with expected output so is easy to other find out created query will match or not

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator in your mongo query because from the **[docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)**:

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma
>   separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and
>   operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be
>   specified in multiple expressions.

Thus this SQL expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pattern_object_values 
WHERE 
   (pattern_object_id = 1  && value > 1977  && value < 1986 )
|| (pattern_object_id = 2  && value > 5000 && value < 950000 );
```

has the MongoDB equivalent:

```
db.pattern_object_values.find({
$or: [ 
         { 
            'pattern_object_id': 1,
            { 
               'value': { '$gt': 1977, '$lt': 1986 } 
            } 
         }, 
         { 
            'pattern_object_id': 2,
            { 
                'value': { '$gt': 5000, '$lt': 950000 } 
            }
         }
     ]  
});
```

which you can then convert to the PHP equivalent (untested)

```
db->pattern_object_values
  ->find(array('$or' => array(
             array(
                  array('pattern_object_id' => 1),
                  array('value' => array('$gt' => 1977, '$lt' => 1986)
             ),
             array(
                  array('pattern_object_id' => 1),
                  array('value' => array('$gt' => 5000, '$lt' => 950000 )
             )
           )
        )
    );
```